# How to add month column to a date column in python?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, timedelta

```
date['Maturity_date'] = data.apply(lambda data: relativedelta(months=int(data['TRM_LNTH_MO'])) + data['POL_EFF_DT'], axis=1)
```

Tried this also:

```
date['Maturity_date'] = date['POL_EFF_DT'] + date['TRM_LNTH_MO'].values.astype("timedelta64[M]")
```

> TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment

Comment: For me working first solution with `date.apply` instead `data.apply` nice.

Comment: Please follow the editing guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

#Convert the date column to date format
date['date_format'] = pd.to_datetime(date['Maturity_date'])

#Add a month column
date['Month'] = date['date_format'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%b'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Pandas, you may use a resource called: "Frequency Aliases". Something very out of the box:

```
# For "periods": 1 (is the current date you have) and 2 the result, plus 1, by the frequency of 'M' (month).

import pandas as pd

_new_period = pd.date_range(_existing_date, periods=2, freq='M')
```

Now you can get exactly the period you want as the second element returned:

```
# The index for your information is 1. Index 0 is the existing date.

_new_period.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')[1]

# You can format in different ways. Only Year, Month or Day. Whatever.
```

[Consult this link for further information](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html)